# MySQL check using forgein key before update

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have problem with updating information in table.There is scheme of problematic [tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imqrJ.png)

When I inserting information into the table `Zamestnanec`, first I insert information into table `Adresa`,`Kontakty` and `Uzivatel`. Then I `SELECT` the primary key for the new row of all three tables and saved to the variable and on the last time I insert information into table `Zamestnanec` with this sql command

```
PreparedStatement pst = db.CreatePreparedStatement("INSERT INTO autoservis.zamestnanec"
                    + "(idZamestnanec,"
                    + "Jmeno,"
                    + "Prijmeni,"
                    + "RodneCislo,"
                    + "Adresa_idAdresa,"
                    + "Kontakty_idKontakty,"
                    + "Uzivatel_idUzivatel)"
                    + "VALUES"
                    + "(null,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            pst.setString(1, jTextFieldJmeno.getText());
            pst.setString(2, jTextFieldPrijmeni.getText());
            pst.setDouble(3, Double.parseDouble(jTextFieldRodneCislo.getText()));
            pst.setInt(4, idAdresa);
            pst.setInt(5, idKontakt);
            pst.setInt(6, idUzivatel);
            pst.execute();
```

When I insert two Zamestnanec with same Adresa and want delete one of this row in table Zamestnanec and also delete row in child table Adresa. Then mysql return

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (autoservis.zamestnanec, CONSTRAINT fk_Zamestananec_Adresa1 FOREIGN
>   KEY (Adresa_idAdresa) REFERENCES adresa (idAdresa) ON DELETE NO ACTION
>   ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

That's allright but when I do update in child table then the change information in row is without problem. But mysql should return the same error Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What part of the "child" table (I assume you actually mean a "parent" table) do you try to update? You can change every column apart from the id.

Comment: So if i understand it right your asking why the update query is not giving any errors?

Comment: Yeah, i have in table Adresa two row with primary id 1 and 2 and i want edit value of "Ulice" in row with primary id 1 .But then all rows in Zamestnanec with zamestnanec.Adresa_idAdresa = 1 have edited value Ulice. and this i dont want. i want insert new row with with new ID and insert to  zamestnanec.Adresa_idAdresa = new ID. foreign key dont work in this situation?

Comment: It is not really clear what you are trying to do. You maybe misunderstood what a foreign key or child/parent table is for. The point of a parent table IS that when you edit its content, every related child "changes" too - so you only have to change it at one place. If you do not want that behaviour, have each Adresa only belong to at most one Zamestnanec (you use an Adresaid only once in the Adresa_idAdresa-column, so if you change an adresa, it only changes at most one Zamestnanec), or you might want to change your data model (e.g. having the "ulice"-column in the Zamestnanec-table).

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Delete from Childtable before you delete from Parenttable. This way you can prevent the Error.

If you want to have all queries atomic (all or nothing) use a transaction.

Comment: If you get this Exception, you either try to set a Not existing Id to AdressaId, or you try to delete a Rowe in adressa which is referenced. So you either have to insert a new Adressa and then Update the other table, or delete first all rows, or AdressaIds, which reference to the row, you are trying to delete.

Comment: If you want to prevent Double-Values, you can also add a unique-Constraint on the Fields or fieldcombination, you want to keep unique.

Comment: Do you know that the Adresa table is the parent table?

Comment: And Zamestnanec is child table?

Comment: Yes because Zamentnanec has the Foreign Key Adresa-Id

Comment: You could also modify the Foreign Key Constraint to ON DELETE CASCADE, then by deleting the Adresa your Zamestnanec will be deleted too, but this Comedy along with the risk of loosing data, if you delete a Adresa which is adressed by two Zamestnanec.